# pass JFrame to a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have a class that creates a JFrame.  When the start button is clicked, it calls my CoinCounterMechanism class.  This class contains the following Thread:

```
Thread consumer = new Thread("CONSUMER"){
    public void run ()
    {
        Integer coin;
        while (producerFlag)
        try 
        {
            coin = queue.take();
            System.out.println("Coin received: " + coin);
        } catch (InterruptedException e)  
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

When this thread gets called from my other class, I need to pass it the JFrame so I can modify the JFrame contents.  How can I do this?  This is for an intro level java course so the teacher gave us most of this code.  Below is the code where the Thread gets called:

```
Button btnStart = new JButton("Start");
    btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            cm = new CoinCounterMechanism();
            cm.setConsumerFlag();
            cm.setProducerFlag();

            cm.producer.start();
            cm.consumer.start();
        }
    });
```

Comment: The only thread that should ever do anything to a `JFrame` is the UI thread.

Comment: Just remember, swing is not thread safe. It might better to use a call back with can be used to synchronize the thread with the EDT or use a SwingWorker

Comment: Consider up-voting helpful answers and accepting the best answer, both for this question and your previous questions. Otherwise you're asking for effort of volunteers and not rewarding them for their efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an anonymous Thread, you create an actual Runnable class.  You use the constructor to pass your JFrame and other fields.

```
public class Consumer implements Runnable {

    private boolean producerFlag;

    private JFrame frame;

    private Queue<Integer> queue;

    public Consumer(JFrame frame, Queue<Integer> queue, boolean producerFlag) {
        this.frame = frame;
        this.queue = queue;
        this.producerFlag = producerFlag;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Integer coin;
        while (producerFlag)
            try {
                coin = queue.take();
                System.out.println("Coin received: " + coin);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

}
```

Your JButton code contains higher level code than the code that actually starts the thread.  In general, you would start a thread with the Runnable class above this way:

```
new Thread(new Consumer(frame, queue, true)).start();
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thread that should be modifying anything on a JFrame is the event dispatch thread.

In order to have another thread modify a Swing component like a JFrame it needs to submit the change on the event dispatch thread, for example having the worker thread use [SwingUtilities#invokeLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29):

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // modify your JFrame here
    }
});
```